# How to make consumer idempotent when publisher publishes "at least once"?

Tags: microservices, message-queue, event-handling

I'm trying to implement microservices and I'm still super new to the subject, but, I was able to answer most of questions.

However, one of the questions that I can't come up with a good solution to is how do I make my consumer idempotent when my publisher publishes at least once?

[image: Graph A]

### What happens without making Consumer idempotent:

Our consumer receives `Event A` multiple times, and `Event A` is asking to pay X dollar to `User A`, without handling this correctly, we've paid `User A` 3 * X times.

### Possible solution

What I've come up with is this solution:

We create an `Events` table in `Service A` (publisher), we create an entity with an `id` and `serviceName` (in this case `serviceA`) inside `Events` table, then we proceed to publish the event.

In `Service B` (consumer), we create a `ReceivedEvents` table, which holds both `eventId` and `serviceName` as primary key, this way, whenever we have a new event, we will first check if the event is inside `ReceivedEvents`, if not, we proceed to complete the task.

Is this approach good enough? Is there an alternative to this approach?

Comment: Will you be horizontally scaling the consumer?

Comment: @uylmz yes, but I'm using kafka with "consumer group"

Comment: Yes, your approach with unique event id is the correct one. A consumer service simply checks whether an event has already been processed and if so discards the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like payments, you would simply append a timestamp to it and shift your DB insert to be “insert into pmts where not exist payment with this amount and this timestamp”. For something like users, the unique constraint might be username.

Entities not in a DB like this will require a different approach. Emails for example might just be fine to duplicate given how infrequently the event duplication happens. Otherwise a transient db/cache owned by the receiving microservice is usually used to persist events for a short while. There can be race conditions there, so take care with your design.

Comment: Thank you for responding, let's say we are super unlucky and `User A` decides to pay 60 dollar to `User B` in 2, 30 dollar payments, which happen at exactly the same time ( so timestamp and amount is the same ), do we accept this kind of "super, super" unlucky events as side effect ( we did not lose money, we just need to make a support channel for user to investigate this rare issue ) or is there an approach to guarantee this wont happen either?

Comment: In practical scenarios, an identical timestamp can’t happen. It’d require two UIs logged in, paying the same amount, and managing to land the request at the same fraction of a millisecond at the API. If you’re concerned about it, then a distributed ID system could guarantee uniqueness at the cost of latency/complexity.

Comment: was wondering how should we decide if we want to keep DBs for each service or use only one event db? Event db could handle the sending email use case, and “insert into pmts where not exist payment with this amount and this timestamp” can also apply to decide if a new event is appended.

Comment: “Can we deploy/scale each microservice independently?”

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda a bad design as the central database undermines the distributed nature of your event queue.

Instead I would make each consumer idempotent in isolation.

ie the PaymentConsumer would record payments made and thus detect duplicate payment requests and reject/ignore them.

the PackageSenderConsumer would similarly record it id of orders it had processed and not send two packages etc etc

This is essentially the same solution without the central 'Events' database

Comment: There will be one database per service, so there's no central database. your examples include an entity, like did I process this `order` ( which is an entity ), did I process this `payment` ( another entity ), what about services that don't have any entity attached to them? for example a `Mail` service which would just send emails based on incoming events?